# Reorder Time/Location data to list point to point trips

Tags: r

I have a df that the first and last recorded time at a particular location. Example raw data linked in code below.

```
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smitty1788/Personal-Website/master/example.csv', header = T)


    address                                   fuel  name    Long        Lat Time
1   625-627 S St NW, Washington, DC 20001, USA  87  EC6502  -77.02081   38.91411    5/18/2017 13:36
2   625-627 S St NW, Washington, DC 20001, USA  87  EC6502  -77.02081   38.91411    5/18/2017 15:28
3   1301-1327 Howard Rd SE, Washington, DC 20020, USA   87  EC6502  -76.99312   38.86101    5/18/2017 16:03
4   1301-1327 Howard Rd SE, Washington, DC 20020, USA   87  EC6502  -76.99312   38.86101    5/18/2017 20:17
5   821 Whittier Pl NW, Washington, DC 20012, USA   81  EC6502  -77.02542   38.97149    5/18/2017 21:03
6   821 Whittier Pl NW, Washington, DC 20012, USA   81  EC6502  -77.02542   38.97149    5/19/2017 8:35
7   1327 Allison St NW, Washington, DC 20011, USA   81  EC6502  -77.03118   38.94508    5/19/2017 8:50
8   1327 Allison St NW, Washington, DC 20011, USA   81  EC6502  -77.03118   38.94508    5/19/2017 8:55
9   815 Whittier Pl NW, Washington, DC 20012, USA   81  EC6502  -77.02481   38.97148    5/19/2017 9:11
10  1655-1699 N Rhodes St, Arlington, VA 22201, USA 100 EP0253  -77.08  38.89306    5/18/2017 13:36
11  1655-1699 N Rhodes St, Arlington, VA 22201, USA 100 EP0253  -77.08  38.89306    5/18/2017 15:02
12  2617 N Stuart St, Arlington, VA 22207, USA  100 EP0253  -77.11257   38.9066 5/18/2017 15:28
13  2617 N Stuart St, Arlington, VA 22207, USA  100 EP0253  -77.11257   38.9066 5/18/2017 16:54
14  1432-1488 N Quincy St, Arlington, VA 22201, USA 100 EP0253  -77.10842   38.8887 5/18/2017 17:14
15  1432-1488 N Quincy St, Arlington, VA 22201, USA 100 EP0253  -77.10842   38.8887 5/18/2017 18:30
16  1020-1028 N Stafford St, Arlington, VA 22201, USA   84  EP0253  -77.11047   38.88278    5/18/2017 23:15
17  1020-1028 N Stafford St, Arlington, VA 22201, USA   84  EP0253  -77.11047   38.88278    5/19/2017 13:53
```

The data would indicate that there was a trip between rows 2 and 3, 4 and 5, 6 and 7 and so on for each individual plate in column "name".

I and trying to figure out an efficient way to reorganize the data so that one row would show starting location and ending location (end_address, end_fuel, end_long, end_lat, end_time). Essentially, each row is one trip made. Ideally the new df would be organized like this

```
name, st_address, st_fuel, st_long, st_lat, st_time, end_address, end_fuel,  end_long,  end_lat,  end_time
```

Would someone be able to help me identify a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: is it valid to assume that except for row 1, an even row number indicates  start data and an odd row number an end data?

Comment: That should be a valid assumption for each unique "name". Though, I just noticed you can also assume the last row for each "name" is repeated at well. You'll notice that the same occurs in row 10 when the name changes from EC6502 to EP0253. All subsequent rows should alternate between start and end data.

Answer (score 1):

A dplyr solution which relies on group_by to identify vehicle names.

```
library(dplyr)

# code each pair with a trip id by dividing by 2 - code each trip as 1 = from, 0 = to
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(trip_id  = (1 + seq_along(address)) %/% 2,
                    from_to  = (seq_along(address) %% 2))

# seprate into from and to
df_from <- df %>% filter(from_to %% 2 == 1) %>% select(-from_to)
df_to   <- df %>% filter(from_to %% 2 == 0) %>% select(-from_to)

# join the result
result <- inner_join(df_from, df_to, by = c("name", "trip_id"))
```

Comment: This definitely works for the first unique "name" in the dataset, however, when there is a name change the solution doesn't ignore the first address instance for that new car. Is it possible to have this essentially restart when it identifies a new name?

Comment: I believe I managed to remove the first and last rows of each "name" group. The solution below seems to work perfectly with the help you provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smitty1788/Personal-Website/master/example.csv', 
           header = T)

# Remove 1st and Last row of each group
df_clean <- df %>%
  mutate(Time = mdy_hm(Time)) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  arrange(name, Time) %>%
  filter(row_number() != 1,
         row_number() != n())


df_tripID <- df_clean %>% 
      group_by(name) %>% 
      mutate(trip_id  = (1 + seq_along(address)) %/% 2,
             from_to  = (seq_along(address) %% 2))

# seprate into from and to
df_from <- df_tripID %>% 
  filter(from_to %% 2 == 1) %>% 
  select(-from_to)
df_to   <- df_tripID %>% 
  filter(from_to %% 2 == 0) %>% 
  select(-from_to)

# join the result
car2go_trips <- inner_join(df_from, df_to, by = c("name", "trip_id"))
```